# Keeping a 'Canonical' Table Consistent With 'Raw' Source Tables

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, triggers

I am using PostgreSQL. I have a number of 'raw' tables derived from data from third parties, for example

```
Table: exchange1_trades

id, trade_id, side,  base_asset, quote_asset, price, quantity
1,  123,      'buy', 'ETH',      'BTC',       0.02,  10
```

```
Table: exchange2_trades

id, asset, trade_id, change
1,  'ETH', 100,      -20
2,  'BTC', 100,      0.3
```

My goal is to combine these into a single consistent canonical table:

```
Table: canonical_trades

id, exchange,    asset, change, trade_id, parent_table,       parent_id,  usd
1,  'exchange1', 'ETH',     10,      123, 'exchange1_trades', 1,          NULL
2,  'exchange1', 'BTC',   -0.2,      123, 'exchange1_trades', 1,          NULL
3,  'exchange2', 'ETH',    -20,      100, 'exchange2_trades', 1,          NULL
4,  'exchange2', 'BTC',    0.3,      100, 'exchange2_trades', 2,          NULL
```

Where the `usd` column will be later populated separately by some external job.

What is the best way to achieve this? I would ideally like:
(1) the `canonical_trades` table to be updated whenever the raw tables have rows added/removed
(2) constraints to ensure `canonical_trades` is in line with the raw tables (e.g. no extra rows)
(3) to be able to add indexes to `canonical_trades`

Some approaches I've considered:

(a) just define `canonical_trades` as a table with no constraints, and have some query or script that will update it to reflect the raw tables. This is simple, but doesn't very strongly guarantee consistency with the raw tables.

(b) define triggers to add/remove entries from the canonical table whenever the raw tables have entries added/removed

(c) define a parent `canonical_trades` table, and have children `exchange1_base_canonical_trades`, `exchange1_quote_canonical_trades`, `exchange2_canonical_trades` that inherit from it. Each child can then have its own foreign key column referencing its parent table.

(d) define views `exchange1_base_view`, `exchange1_quote_view`, `exchange2_view` each containing the relevant rows, then form canonical trades as `exchange1_base_view UNION ALL exchange1_quote_view UNION ALL exchange2_view`. The downside here is that there isn't an easy way to add the `usd` column - I'd need a separate table, and the join gets messy.

Comment: I assume `exchange` is redundant, as it always equals to `split_part(parent_table, '_', 1)`. Also `change` of `base_asset` equals to `quantity`, and `change` of `quota_asset` equals to `-price * quantity`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct on all three counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have only 2 options:

1. Have physical storage for the canonical table or;
2. Have a view build from the normalized tables

What you will select depends on

1. What is more important, faster `INSERT` or faster `SELECT`
2. Do you need the exact last value or any last value as long as it's correct and in sequence.
3. Number of times `SELECT` is issued on the canonical table compared to the number of times `INSERT` is issued to the non-canonical tables
4. Types of queries that will be run on the canonical table (read only or read-write)
5. Different variations of the `SELECT` queries that will be executed on the canonical table.

Let's take this considerations one by one

1. If you need faster response time for `INSERT` statements, then the view is preferred option, since the trigger will operate across multiple tables, hanse it will be slower. On the other hand, if the `SELECT` needs to be faster (ex. you need to make a decision on the canonical table and this needs to be done fast), then the trigger is the preferred option since the data will be prepared (joined) in the table
2. Although this might sound as a strange question, allowing the read of stale data, you can decide to use the view approach, but enhance it to be a `materialized view` in which case there will be a physical storage behind the view. The refresh can be scheduled on a given period ex 1h, 1day, etc.
3. If you have huge ratio between `SELECT` and `INSERT` (ex. 1k to 1, 10k to 1, etc.) then the database will benefit from having a physical storage behind the canonical table (this means using a trigger or materialized view).
4. If you need to modify the data in the canonical table, you will need to have a physical storage behind it. This means you will need to have a table or `instead of insert` trigger. Which one you select, depends on the frequency and complexity of the updates.
5. If you have different variations of the `SELECT` statements, you will face the need to have indexes behind the canonical table to improve the performance. To have indexes, you will need to have physical storage behind the canonical table.

So in conclusion:

If you need to have physical storage for the table, based on the ability to use stale data you will decide to use triggers (no stale data) or materialized view (stale data). If you don't need to have physical storage, than a simple view will suffice.

> As a note, the inheritance in this case will not help you since you have multiple version of the same data, but in cases where it is possible, the inheritance is just another way to organize the physical data, for the purpose of the above analyses you can consider it as a way of having physical storage.